# Update Cart Page by Ajax on quantity change

Tags: cart, ajax, magento-2.1.7

I have to update the main cart on change of quantity by Ajax without click on "Update Cart Button" and without reloading the page.
By the following code, I'm able to update cart table but m not getting a solution to update the "Cart Summary" block.

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'], function ($) {
    // $("#submitbutton").hide();
    var form = $('form#form-validate');
    var qtyfields = $('input.qty');
    $('.page.messages').each(function () {
        var thismessage = $(this);
        thismessage.attr('id', 'messages');
    });

    form.find(qtyfields).each(function (e) {
        var thisfield = $(this);
        $(this).change(function () {
            console.log('change detected');
            form.submit();
        });

    });
    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            success: function (res) {
                var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);
                //console.log(result);
                //location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
        console.log('form submitted');
    });
});
</script>
```

Please give me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

This code only will submit once if call the

```
$("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);
```

And Ajax returning a whole HTML page for the result.

Is there any way to just get back small string of a JSON data set instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one, it works fine for me:

> - var parsedResponse = jQuery.parseHTML(res);
> - var result = jQuery(parsedResponse).find(".subtotal");
> - var result1 = jQuery(parsedResponse).find(".message");
> - jQuery(".subtotal").replaceWith(result);
> - jQuery(".message").replaceWith(result1);